# How to join a apple development team?

Tags: certificate, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile, apple-developer

I was invited to iTunes connect by an organization and I accepted it. I was trying to get access to developer.apple.com, but it says I don't have a team. I do have access to itunesconnect.apple.com but not the certificate site.

What am I supposed to do to get access to the developer certificate site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whoever owns the developer account has added you as an iTunes Connect role, which is different than a Developer Program role (see more [here](https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/)).

You need to have the owner of the developer team account log into developer.apple.com.  When they do, select the "People" link on the first page.  From there, have them click the "Invite People" button.  Then they can enter your email address as either a member or an admin.  See the link above as to which Developer Program role you should be assigned to.

If you need to do certificate and provisioning profile management, you will need to be an admin.