# Team not showing on iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, itunes

I have a paid individual Apple iTunes Connect account and one of my clients wants to upload the current iOS application developed to their Account.
So they added me as a member of their iTunes account. I accepted the invitation but the team is not listed anywhere in my iTunes connect.
What should be the issue?
What should I do next to upload my currently developed app to their account with new certificates? Do I need to change Developer, Distribution and Provision certificates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are added as Developer in itunes you can upload the app using that account. But in order to get the certificates you need to login to https://developer.apple.com/ and generate the certificate and provisioning profile. iTunes account is different from Developer account. Refer this https://clearbridgemobile.com/how-to-submit-an-app-to-the-app-store/

Comment: The invitation is: ---- has invited you to join a development team, ***** , in the Apple Developer Program. Please respond within 30 days. If you have any questions, contact ------. You are saying, I also need to be an iTunes connect team member?

Comment: @KrishnakumarCN. Can you login to https://developer.apple.com/ and see whether you have access to certificate and profile. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48292748/6818278

Comment: do we need a separate invitation for iTunes connect?

Comment: @VinodRadhakrishnan Yes, you need to add as App store connect users under USERS AND ROLES